# Apache alias virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost, mod-alias

I have two applications running in the same server and I would like to have one served from subpath in the url (i.e):

- foo.com -> /var/www/foo
- foo.com/bar -> /var/www/bar

I'm trying to do an alias but is not working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@foo.com
  ServerName foo.com
  DocumentRoot /webapps/foo/current/public
  <Directory /webapps/foo/current/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  RailsEnv staging
  Alias /blog /webapps/blog/current
 <Directory /webapps/blog/current>
   allow from all
   Options +Indexes
 </Directory>
```

Do you know why this is not working?

I also tried serverpath directive without any success.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your virtualhost working at all? Cos if you need to access it via `www.` as well as the root of the domain, I would say you need a `ServerAlias www.foo.com` in there...

Comment: Also, does either app use any `mod_rewrite`ing?

Comment: Oh sorry, actually the address is without the www. I fixed that on the post. The virtualhost is working, I'm able to access it, but if I go to /blogs/ it does nothing. 

Both applications have mon_rewrite inside their .httaccess

Comment: What do you get? A 404? And what is in the Apache logs? And are you using a `[PT]` on you rewrite rules for the `/blogs` directory?

Comment: I get a 404 that is handled by /var/www/foo. I don't have a [PT] rewrite rule. Actually I don't have a rewrite for the /blog... I'm using for other things. Should I have a rewrite and the alias in order to make it work?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on your app - it's just that some rewrite rules wont work with aliases unless you have a `[PT]` (although not all rules, it depends on what it does). Let me have a play with the Apache install on my laptop and I'll get back to you...

Comment: what about using a subdomain such as bar.foo.com. This way it will have its own vhost configuration.

Comment: the subdomain is the way I have it know, but we wanted to change it to the other way.

Comment: Besides tuning apache configuration, have you ever tried create a symbolic link `/var/www/bar` to `/var/www/foo/bar`

Answer (score 3):

Use `AliasMatch` instead of `Alias`:

```
AliasMatch ^/bar/?(.*) /var/www/bar/$1
```

Or, in your case:

```
AliasMatch ^/blog/?(.*) /webapps/blog/current/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using another separate subdomain, like `bar.foo.com` for your other application?

Here's how you'd set that up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@foo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias foo.com www.foo.com
    ErrorLog logs/foo.com_Error_Log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@foo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bar
    ServerName bar.foo.com
    ErrorLog logs/bar.foo.com_Error_Log
</VirtualHost>
```